# Angular 2 Init Service with Values

Tags: angular

i have an shared module with an resource service in it. In my app.module i want to import this module and init the resource service with values. So my components defined in share.module can use the resources (translations).

P.S. I don't want to init the resource service within providers of app.module.
The share module should be self-contained.

share.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
    declarations: [ ComponentA, ComponentB],
    providers: [ResourceService], ...
```

app.module.ts

```
import [ ShareModule ]
```

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.http.get("resource").subscribe(resource => {
       // init resource service of share module here
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me how i can achieve it?

Best regards

Comment: Does share module make API call?

Comment: No. ShareModule is a module to define components. It should be a library. But i dont know how to do it yet ^_^. The components within it should not call API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Angular documentation says:](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)

> The most common way to get a hold of shared services is through
>   Angular dependency injection, rather than through the module system
>   (importing a module will result in a new service instance, which is
>   not a typical usage).

Create injectable service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  // we declare that this service should be created
  // by the root application injector.
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {
  getYourData() { /* make here http call...;*/ }
}
```

Then you can use dependency injection in your constructor:

```
constructor(yourService: YourService) {
}
```

and you call anywhere this service:

```
this.http.get("resource").subscribe(resource => {
   // call your service
   this.fooData = yourService.getYourData();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{providedIn: 'root'}` for your service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ResourceService {}
```

And remove it from `providers`.

Then create another class which will hold the configuration for the `SharedModule`:

```
// Change this for your needs
export abstract class SharedConfig {
  readonly api: string;
}
```

Then create a `forRoot` on your `SharedModule` class:

```
export class SharedModule {

  public static forRoot(configFactory, deps = []): ModuleWithProviders {

    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: SharedConfig, useFactory: configFactory, deps: deps}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
imports: [SharedModule.forRoot({api: 'https://foo.com/api'})]
```

Now in your service you can inject this config like this:

```
constructor(private config: SharedConfig) {
  // logs 'https://foo.com/api'
  console.log(config.api);
}
```

This will allow you to get the values from the `forRoot` call.